# Possible null pointer dereference - otherwise it is redundant to check it against null

Tags: c++, cppcheck

I have the following code, which is working properly:

```
int result = ERRORCODE_OK;
if (dataObj == NULL || dataObj->inputSignal == NULL)
{
   result = ERRORCODE_MISSING_DATAOBJ;
}
if (result == ERRORCODE_OK && dataObj->spectrum == NULL) // CPP-Check error
{
   result = Calculate(dataObj->inputSignal, .. );
} 
return result;
```

But CppCheck gives me the following error:

> Possible null pointer dereference: `dataObj` - otherwise it is redundant to check it against null.

I don't understand why. If the `dataobj` is `NULL`, then the result will be something else then `ERRORCODE_OK`.

Comment: _" If the dataobj is NULL, then the result will be something else then ERRORCODE_OK."_ Why do you assume cppcheck just knows that?

Comment: Change the 2nd if to else if and i guess it will work. You don't need to check the 2nd "if" when dataObj is nullptr anyway.

Comment: I try to reproduce this in cppcheck online checker and fail to do this. May be online checker is weaker than offline one, or you have different settings. So can you reproduce it in online checker?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CppCheck doesn't inspect deep enough to see that your second condition won't be fully evaluated if the first one succeeds:

```
int result = ERRORCODE_OK;
if (dataObj == NULL || dataObj->inputSignal == NULL)
    result = ERRORCODE_MISSING_DATAOBJ;

// Here, you can see that either dataObj!=NULL or result!=ERRORCODE_OK.
// But CppCheck can't!

if (result == ERRORCODE_OK && dataObj->spectrum == NULL)
    result = Calculate(dataObj->inputSignal, .. );
return result;
```

Three alternative ways of pacifying the checker present themselves.  Firstly, just repeat the check that `dataObj` is non-null in the second `if`.  Secondly, change the second `if` to `else if`:

```
int result = ERRORCODE_OK;
if (dataObj == NULL || dataObj->inputSignal == NULL)
{
    result = ERRORCODE_MISSING_DATAOBJ;
}
else if (result == ERRORCODE_OK && dataObj->spectrum == NULL)
{
    result = Calculate(dataObj->inputSignal, .. );
} 
return result;
```

Thirdly, return as soon as you find one of the error cases:

```
if (!dataObj || !dataObj->inputSignal)
    return ERRORCODE_MISSING_DATAOBJ;
if (dataObj->spectrum)
    return ERRORCODE_OK;
return Calculate(dataObj->inputSignal, .. );
```

Answer (score 4):

It happens because you check that variable for `NULL` here:

```
if (dataObj == NULL || dataObj->inputSignal == NULL)
```

This makes the analyzer think that `dataObj` can, in some circumstances, be `NULL`.

Now, Cppcheck can't know the logic behind your code, there is no way for it to know that `result == ERRORCODE_OK` ensures that `dataObj != NULL`, so it gives you the warning about your second `if`. Basically it assumes that if you check a variable for `NULL` in the first condition, then it makes sence to check it for `NULL` in the second condition too.

Note that it says "**Possible** null pointer dereference", so in your case it's just a false-positive.

Answer (score 2):

My theory - You are checking against null in the first if so the checked assumes that dataObj can be null, and then in the second if you use dataObj without checking if it can be null so the checked is flagging a possible real problem.

Your code sets result result though so it will never actually happend.... Perhaps the checker isn't clever enough to notice that the problem can't actually happen.

Answer (score 1):

In general these tool check for `NULL check statement` which hints them that this object can be null so after null check if you are trying to refer that it will show error. It is good practice to return if anything wrong happens if possible or keep the referring code out of reach. You can rearrange your `if` statements to achieve that or add `return` in your first `if` .