# Either the condition is redundant or there is possible null pointer dereference

Tags: c, pointers, sonarqube, static-code-analysis, cppcheck

I wrote a C code for an embedded system and when I execute the code analysis with SonarQube and CppCheck plugin I get this bug:

> Either the condition is redundant or there is possible null pointer dereference: pointer.

This is the code that has the bug:

```
ReturnCode_e SocketTcpSecureWrite( SocketHandle_t socketHandle, 
                                   char* dataBuffer, 
                                   uint16_t dataBufferLen, uint16_t* byteTransmitted )
{
    uint32_t bytes = 0;
    ReturnCode_e opResult = SSL_WRITE_ERROR;

    *byteTransmitted = 0;

    if( dataBuffer == NULL || byteTransmitted == NULL )
    {
        return WRONG_PARAMETER;
    }

    if( SEND_SOCKET( socketHandle, dataBuffer, dataBufferLen, 0, &bytes ) == SUCCESS )
    {
        *byteTransmitted = bytes;
        opResult = SUCCESS;
    }

    return opResult;
}
```

I don't understand why the pointer consistency check appears as a bug. 
I want to verify that the pointer is not NULL before execute the function, otherwise I return an error.

Is this the right way to check the pointer consistency?

Comment: The code trivially looks fine, are you sure this is the *exact* code generating the warning?

Comment: Show the rest of the code. Also CppCheck will complain about a specifc line...

Comment: I added the screenshot captured from SonarQube

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Possible null pointer dereference - otherwise it is redundant to check it against null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32839786/possible-null-pointer-dereference-otherwise-it-is-redundant-to-check-it-agains)

Comment: I've marked it as duplicate. I think you're using `byteTransmitted` after the if statement (return). CppCheck analysis isn't deep enough for that. It's a false positive.

Comment: I attached the entire function code

Comment: As I said, it's because of this line: `*byteTransmitted = bytes;`. CppCheck doesn't know that you returned before this if `byteTransmitted == NULL` and sees no check before it. Your code is fine!

Comment: @AndreKampling Thanks for the explanation! Now it's clear!

Comment: So, we have a wrapper function around a wrapper function around `write()` and we use a silly tool to check the wrapper functions, and the tool fails...

Comment: @AndreKampling It's not a false positive: the problem is `*byteTransmitted = 0;` _before_ the `NULL` check.

Comment: @wildplasser No, the tool worked. The code fails.

Comment: @TripeHound: Ahhh I did not see that line before the if statement because first he didn't post his full code. He edited that... Thank you!

Comment: @AndreKampling Sorry: it all says "4 hours ago" (at time of commenting) -- I assumed the full code was there when you commented.

Comment: @TripeHound: That's right but first it wasn't (watch edit history) and I assumed what I've already explained. Then he posted the full code and I did not see the line and feeled like I was right but I was not. Thank you! Further watch at the screenshots in the edit history CppCheck complains about the if statement. But nevertheless also if he put the line below the if statement CppCheck will give the warning because of what I was saying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I looked through the code and checked it, immediately using PVS-Studio and it also issued a warning:

[V595](https://www.viva64.com/en/w/V595/): The 'byteTransmitted' pointer was utilized before it was verified against nullptr. Check lines: 39, 41. consoleapplication1.cpp 39

Indeed, let's look at this code fragment:

```
*byteTransmitted = 0;

if( dataBuffer == NULL || byteTransmitted == NULL )
```

In the beginning the pointer `byteTransmitted` is dereferenced, and only after that it is verified against `NULL`. It is an error. So, it is right that all analyzers complain about it. It will be correct firstly to verify and only then use the pointer:

```
if( dataBuffer == NULL || byteTransmitted == NULL )
{
  return WRONG_PARAMETER;
}

*byteTransmitted = 0;
```

Comment: I think CppCheck will still give the warning because of what I already mentioned in the above comments: [Possible null pointer dereference - otherwise it is redundant to check it against null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32839786/possible-null-pointer-dereference-otherwise-it-is-redundant-to-check-it-agains). Nevertheless your answer fixes a problem with his code!

Comment: @PaulR: Yes sure! But I mean CppCheck will also warn after the correction.

Comment: @AndreyKarpov: Now I understand the reason behind the error! It's clear! Thanks for testing my code

Comment: @AndreKampling I am a Cppcheck developer. I don't agree about "CppCheck will also warn after the correction". Not for this example code at least. Perhaps for your real code. Then you might have one more bug in your real code.

Comment: @Daniel: Hi thank you that you take part of the discussion. What's about the link I've posted? It's the same case here: Check of a variable against NULL --> return if NULL --> After that use the variable. Does I get something wrong? Was this fixed long time ago?

Comment: @AndreKampling About that link, I agree it is a false positive but as far as I see latest Cppcheck does not write a false positive for that. The code example is not complete so maybe I missed some detail when I tested it - please try on your real code also.

Comment: @Daniel: I Have no real code as I'm not the OP of this question.

Comment: @Daniel: But yes you're right I've tested the current Cppcheck version and it will not complain after the correction of the answerer.